# Calculating Login - Break - LogoutTimes

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns

```
AgentID    Status       EventTime
-----------------------------------------
agent1     Login        20150101 08:30
agent1     Break        20150101 11:00
agent1     Available    20150101 12:00
agent1     WorkOffline  20150101 3:00
agent1     logout       20150101 4:00
agent2     Login        20150101 08:30
agent2     Break        20150101 11:00
agent2     Available    20150101 12:00
agent2     WorkOffline  20150101 3:00
agent2     logout       20150101 4:00
```

I'm trying to calculate the intervals between each of the event types.  Basically create another table with 4 columns:

```
agent   TimeAvailable     TimeonBreak     TimeWorkingOffline
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I already saw some ideas online for just a login and logout logic, by using two tables, one for logins and one for logouts but couldn't see how that applies here, thanks for any advice...

Comment: `lag()` is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Which RDBMS you're using? In general, highly ineffective sql could be something like:

```
SELECT 
        Agent
        ,EventTime as LoginTime
        ,(
            SELECT MIN(EventTime)
            FROM SessionTable S2
            WHERE
                S2.Status = 'Break'
                AND S2.Agent = S.Agent
                AND S2.EventTime > S.EventTime
        )As NextBreak
        ,.. datediff between LoginTime and NextBreak
    FROM 
        SessionTable S
    WHERE
        Status = 'Login'
```

I hope you understand idea.

Answer (score 0):

Bit longwinded but should do what you want (based on the way your data seems to flow):-

```
select
    AgentID,
    DATEDIFF(hh,
            (select 
                EventTime 
             from yourTable i2
             where i2.Status = 'Available' and i2.AgentID = i1.agentID),
             (select 
                EventTime 
             from yourTable i2
             where i2.Status = 'WorkOffline' and i2.AgentID = i1.agentID)) as TimeAvailable,
    DATEDIFF(hh,
            (select 
                EventTime 
             from yourTable i2
             where i2.Status = 'Break' and i2.AgentID = i1.agentID),
             (select 
                EventTime 
             from yourTable i2
             where i2.Status = 'Available' and i2.AgentID = i1.agentID)) as TimeOnBreak,
    DATEDIFF(hh,
            (select 
                EventTime 
             from yourTable i2
             where i2.Status = 'WorkOffline' and i2.AgentID = i1.agentID),
             (select 
                EventTime 
             from yourTable i2
             where i2.Status = 'logout' and i2.AgentID = i1.agentID)) as TimeWorkingOffline 
from yourTable i1
group by AgentID
```